# Python executable to use in hash-bang line?

Tags: python, shell

On Linux, my Python programs begin with

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

If my program is actually written in Python 3.x, should I use `python` or `python3` in that line?

IIRC there was a reason to not use `python3`, but I cannot remember it (or google it).

Comment: It depends up on the script written in which version py3 or py2. Just check the version and provide it. It seems like you want to run the python script with Unix script . If that's the case already i posted the question refer my profile for that questions like : How to embedd other script within Unix script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `#!/usr/bin/env python3` is the most reliable method.

[PEP 0394](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394) suggests system
maintainers to install `python2` and `python3` commands:

> We expect Unix-like software distributions (including systems like
> macOS and Cygwin) to install the python2 command into the default path
> whenever a version of the Python 2 interpreter is installed, and the
> same for python3 and the Python 3 interpreter.
>
> When invoked, python2 should run some version of the Python 2
> interpreter, and python3 should run some version of the Python 3
> interpreter.

Of course this is only a recommendation but it works like that in
practice, at least on Linux systems. For example, on Slackware
-current:

```
$ python2 --version
Python 2.7.18
$ python3 --version
Python 3.8.5
```

And on Fedora 33:

```
$ python2 --version
Python 2.7.18
$ python3 --version
Python 3.9.1
```

Furthermore, it doesn't enforce `python` to always mean Python 2 or
Python 3:

> Distributors may choose to set the behavior of the python command as follows:
>
> python2,
>
> python3,
>
> not provide python command,
>
> allow python to be configurable by an end user or a system administrator.

And this is where Linux distributions differ. On Slackware current:

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.18
```

On Fedora 33:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.9.1
```

That would mean that your script which is written in Python 3 but uses
`#!/usr/bin/env python` would be interpreted by Python 2.7.18 on
Slackware and hence would most likely not work correctly. Using
`python3` in shebang is also good if every try to run your script on
an old Linux system that doesn't even have Python 3 installed (really,
there are old systems out there that are still used) as it would not
even start letting you know immediately that something is wrong.

Furthermore, PEP 0394 moves on to encouraging using virtual
environments or containers such as Docker:

> Encourage your end users to use a virtual environment. This makes the
> user's environment more predictable (possibly resulting in fewer
> issues), and helps avoid disrupting their system.
>
> For scripts that are only expected to be run in an activated virtual
> environment, shebang lines can be written as #!/usr/bin/env python, as
> this instructs the script to respect the active virtual environment.
>
> Applications designed exclusively for a specific environment (such
> as a container or virtual environment) may continue to use the
> python command name.

But of course in practice it's not going to be easy to make your users
always run your script in a virtual environment. Docker containers are
easy to use and share and I'm always glad when maintainers public
Docker image of their software but if your Python script is small,
uses only packages from standard library it may not make sense to use
Docker.

Comment: Thanks for your verbose answer, and the mentioning of PEP394.  That PEP394 settles it for me, and I must have misremembered.